# Maven tool is not set in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this stage in my Jenkins pipeline:

```
   stage('Build') {
       def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
       sh '''for f in i7j-*; do
                 (cd $f && ${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean package)
             done
             wait'''
   }
```

In *Jenkins » Manage Jenkins » Global Tool Configuration* I have a Maven installation called `M3`, version `3.3.9`.

[image: Global Tool Configuration » Maven Installations]

When running this pipeline, `mvnHome` is empty because I get this in the log:

```
+ /bin/mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/***SNIP***/script.sh: 3: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/***SNIP***/script.sh: /bin/mvn: not found
```

I did find a path `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/M3` on the Jenkins server, which works, but I would prefer not to use a hard coded path to mvn in this script.

How do I fix this?

---

**EDIT**: Summary of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42693589/766786), using `tool` and `withEnv`.

My working code is now:

```
   stage('Build') {
        def mvn_version = 'M3'
        withEnv( ["PATH+MAVEN=${tool mvn_version}/bin"] ) {
        sh '''for f in i7j-*; do
                (cd $f && mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none  | tee ../jel-mvn-$f.log) &
              done
              wait'''
        }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you calling mvn several times but using only a single log file (jel-maven.log)?

Comment: Actually it seems fine. Can you share your 'Global Tool Configuration' changes?

Comment: I added a screenshot because one picture says more than a thousand words.

Comment: @khmarbaise This is taken from an existing shell script, run locally, that I am moving to Jenkins. It starts a separate sub-shell for each item in the `for`-loop, and then sends that sub-shell to the background with `&`, so they run in parallel. The `wait` command tells the script to wait until all sub-shells are done. By running them in parallel, that stage goes from 54s on average to 27s. Output is now lumped together in one file, a possible improvement could be to output each sub-shell to a separate file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use your Tools in Jenkinsfile with the `tool` and `withEnv` snippets.

Should looks like this:

```
def mvn_version = 'M3'
withEnv( ["PATH+MAVEN=${tool mvn_version}/bin"] ) {
  //sh "mvn clean package"
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `Jenkinsfile`, never used it before. Will have to research. As far as I understand, `Jenkinsfile` is per repository? I have 6 repos in this pipeline.

Comment: Jenkinsfile is just the approach to store your Jenkins Pipeline in your version control system. So if you have everything important in the Pipline Script and all Post Actions have steps you could use a Jenkinsfile instead of scripting in the Jenkins Webgui. However commands and snippets are the same between Jenkinsfile and Jenkins Webgui so you can use the above for your problem.

Comment: I tested the solution with `tool` and `withEnv`, and this works for me. Accepting answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way should be to use is `tools` directives:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven 'M3'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`M3` is the name pre-configured in Global Tool Configuration, see the docs: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools

Comment: Is there a way to add the tools directive using the Blue Ocean UI?

Comment: i did the same way. but it is saying mvn is not recognized from batch command

Answer (score 1):

What about using the construct:

```
withMaven(mavenOpts: MAVEN_OPTS, maven: 'M3', mavenLocalRepo: MAVEN_LOCAL_REPOSITORY, mavenSettingsConfig: MAVEN_SETTINGS) {
    sh "mvn ..."
}
```

Comment: Nope. `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MAVEN_OPTS for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

Comment: It's a pity that this answer doesn't work, because this construction was one of the first I found when googling before asking.

Comment: In a pipeline script those environment vars need to be prefixed with `env.` i.e. `withMaven(mavenOpts: env.MAVEN_OPTS, maven: 'M3', mavenLocalRepo: env.MAVEN_LOCAL_REPOSITORY, mavenSettingsConfig: env.MAVEN_SETTINGS)` or `withMaven(mavenOpts: "${env.MAVEN_OPTS}", maven: 'M3', mavenLocalRepo: "${env.MAVEN_LOCAL_REPOSITORY}", mavenSettingsConfig: "${env.MAVEN_SETTINGS}")`